# Is there a way to select any other user than message.author.id?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I wanted to make a command which will assign the role to a user, but I don't want it to be the message author. Can anyone suggest me how to do that? Thanks!

Here is the message.author version of the code!

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
if message.content.upper().startswith('!ROLE ADMIN', userID):
    role = get(message.server.roles, id="517064875134943262")
    userID = message.author.id
    if not "343249790047485952" in [role.id for role in 
message.author.roles]:
        return
    elif "517064875134943262" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'You are already an admin 
<@%s>' % (userID))
    else:
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Admin given to <@%s>' % 
(userID))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

The easiest way is to use the `discord.ext.commands` extension with a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters).

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import User, Role

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="role")
async def _role(ctx, role: Role, user:User=None):
    user = user or ctx.message.author
    await client.add_roles(user, role)
    await bot.say("Added role {} to user {}".format(role.mention, user.mention))

bot.run("token")
```

This lets you specify the role you want to give by using its name/mention: `!role @AdminRole @User`

If you want to stick with using `on_message`, you can also access [`message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) to get the list of users who were mentioned in the message.